# Extract all except part of the END of the string using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have records in a Postgres database table in which I have extraneous data in a particular column. I want to select everything except that piece of text from that column. That piece of text is at the end of the data in the column. If that text appears before or in the middle of the product_name, it should not be removed.

How can I compose the select statement? Below is the data and I want to remove the word 'test2' from the result set.

```
id|product_name    |owner
---------------------
12|sissors test2   |23
13|Sample test2    |43
14|test2scoop test2   |43
```

Comment: why not filter it before you insert it in the first place?

Comment: dont have that option. :-/

Comment: then one option is to create a postgresql stored procedure that you can run which will run throught the rows and fix them up using some regular expressions.

Comment: Am I missing the obvious, or does the input data not include `test3`, so anything that selects all the data works?

Answer (score 2):

Something like following should work:

```
SELECT id, replace(product_name, 'test3', '') AS product_name, owner FROM ...
```

Comment: +1: Quite sufficient for the task.  It's good to provide a URL so that the OP learns how to fish as well as being given today's fish.

Answer (score 2):

What does the PostgreSQL manual section on [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) suggest to you?

> `regexp_replace(string text, pattern text, replacement text [, flags text])`
>
> Replace substring(s) matching a POSIX regular expression. See Section 9.7.3 for more information.
>
> `regexp_replace('Thomas', '.[mN]a.', 'M')`

Hence:

```
SELECT id, regex_replace(product_name, 'test3', '') AS product_name, owner
  FROM data -- since the table is anonymous in the question
```

And that's the complicated one — there's also `replace` for straight-text mapping (a little further through the list of functions on the manual page), which would suffice for the task on hand.

```
SELECT id, replace(product_name, 'test3', '') AS product_name, owner
  FROM data -- since the table is anonymous in the question
```

Comment: PS: You can replace the version number in the documentation links with "current" to get the latest version whatever it happens to be; for example: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: @muistooshort: Thanks — that is useful to know.  Link updated; it now goes to the 9.2 documentation, instead of the 9.1 version that Google sent me to.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of links in Google that go to ancient versions like 8.3 or even 7.1, I think that's the main reason for preferring the "current" links, maybe we can even use the popularity of SO so game Google in the right direction :)

Comment: Doesn't work. There are records with test3 before the word and inside the word, like this: "test2sissors", "test2 paper", "papertest2clips"

Comment: I just want to remove the last part of the product_name which contains `" test2"` at the end of the product

Comment: So the regex would be `' test2$'` or perhaps `' test2 *$'`.  One advantage of regular expressions is that you can control things fairly carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing about what you want, but perhaps this will do:

```
select id
     , replace(product_name,' test2,'') as product_name
     , owner
from my_table
```

I'm also guessing that you meant "test2" instead of "test3".

Also note I'm showing a leading blank in the search string.  That's based on the example data provided.

Comment: Good point about the leading space.  That works fine with the sample data — and works unless the word appears at the start of the string, or as part of a bigger 'word' but should still be removed.